# How to interpret 喜んでもらえて私も嬉しいです

Tags: giving-and-receiving

In reply to my thank-you-message I received the following:

> 喜んでもらえて私も嬉しいです。

Can it be interpreted as "I am glad that you enjoyed it"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Exactly. ^_^ There are other subtle ways someone might choose to translate this, but your interpretation is spot on.